# Making Both Menu and Submenu Items Scrollable Using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, overflow

I'm having difficulty making both the menu items and submenu items scrollable when there's overflow in the vertical direction. I'm using the overscroll-y property to enable scrolling on both the parent menu and its children menus.

Although it works fine when used independently, combining them results in the submenu items being hidden.

My hypothesis is that using overscroll-y on the parent menu item causes the children menus, which are supposed to pop up when hovering over "Menu item 1.2", to become children of the parent's layout. By setting overscroll-x to "scroll", these submenus can be made visible.

However, I'm still stuck and unable to find a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[You can reproduce the issue using this simple SAMPLE] : https://codepen.io/mdjf/pen/rNZPExO

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
      <ul>
        <div>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.2</a>
            <ul>
              <div>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.6</a></li>
               </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.7</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin:     0;
  padding:    0;
}

nav ul li {
  float:            left;
  position:         relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display:          block;
  padding:          10px;
  color:            #333;
  text-decoration:  none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

/* Submenu Item 1 */
nav ul ul {
  display:          none;
  position:         absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul ul div {
 max-height:          100px;
 overflow-y:          scroll;
 overflow-x:          clip;
 overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

nav ul ul li {
  min-width: 160px;
}

nav ul ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

/* Submenu Item 2 */
nav ul ul ul {
  display:  none;
  position: absolute;
  left:     160px;
  top:      10px;
  width:    160px;
}

nav ul ul ul div {
 max-height:          100px;
 overflow-y:          scroll;
 overflow-x:          clip;
 overscroll-behavior: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer :

For me the "point of resolution" was to reached by setting the properties of the second submenu css style with :

**position: fixed;**

**overflow-y: auto;**

I recommend to test the snippet in full page mode.

```css
.submenu-level-0 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;

  z-index: 0;
  padding: 10px;

  list-style: none;
}

.submenu-level-0 li {
  position: relative;
}

.submenu-level-0 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu-level-0 > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-level-1 {
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;

  min-width: 170px;
  max-width: 270px;
  max-height: 150px;
  left: 10px;

  padding: 10px;

  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: clip;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;

  background-color: #f0f;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  list-style: none;
}

.submenu-level-1 > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

.submenu-level-2 {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  position: fixed; /* solver */
  top: 170px;
  left: 180px;
  max-height: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto; /* solver */
  overflow-behavior: contain;
  background-color: yellow;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<a> Hover on Menu Item 1 and on Menu Item 1.2, to make the submenu items pop</a>
<br>
<a> The point is having both menu items and submenu items scrollable</a>

<div>
  <ul class="submenu-level-0">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
      <ul class="submenu-level-1">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.2</a>
          <ul class="submenu-level-2">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2.6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1.9</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```